# Alias/Redirect Page Type in Composite C1

Tags: c1-cms

I have the following structure:

Area
- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3

Navigating to Area should be equivalent to navigating to Page 1.

I don't want to solve it using Routes, because I want an editor to be able to set up a similar structure and edit "Area" to point to "Page 1".

How can I create a Page Type where I can set a target page as a setting, and make the page result in a redirect instead of page content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would insert the function named `Composite.Web.Response.Redirect` into the page content of ***Area***.

You would need to switch to Source Mode of the page to be able to insert it, since the function doesn't return anything and the function-selector in Visual Mode only shows functions that returns actual content.

Comment: Sounds very promising, and I can find the function in the functions page. However, I can't select it when I add a function in the page content of the page. The only subfolder in Composite.Web is Html.

Comment: Updated my answer with requirement of switching to Source Mode.

Comment: Beautiful solution! Great editor experience in the Source Mode as well! Thank you. :)